# Why const variable is getting modified using pointers?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc, constants

```
const int var = 10;

var = 20; // error: can not modify a const object



const int var = 10;

int *ptr = &var;

*ptr = 20; // valid
```

(os:Linux compiler: Gcc)

Why *const* var is getting modified using pointers?